# Reinstalled Ubuntu, now have duplicate folders on both drives; cant access necesary ones

Tags: partitioning, apache2, lamp, xampp

Reinstalled Ubuntu on my pc, because the system crashed. Previously I had all my folders in one data storage, but now I separated the drive. I have 68GB Volume, and Computer. Problem is, that both data storages have same folders. Volume storage have all the previous data, but Computer has same folders, but some are empty. Like opt folder. When I try to start Xampp in terminal with `sudo /opt/ampp/lampp start`, it says:

```
sudo: /opt/lampp/lampp: command not found.
```

I'm assuming it's because there is no lampp folder in opt, under my Computer storage. My xampp installation is now at the Volume storage partition.

How do I make the system look in the correct directory?

```
egils@linux:~$ cat /etc/fstab
UUID=1ddb33aa-6ea5-478e-95df-6559477dfb70 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=2b3c62b4-ef69-4c19-aa30-c6a97e70d7a3 none            swap    sw              0       0

egils@linux:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   1  14,4G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1  14,4G  0 part /media/egils/UBUNTU 16_0
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
sda      8:0    0 111,8G  0 disk 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0     8G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda1   8:1    0  63,5G  0 part /media/egils/866e4a3f-54dd-4b90-807e-a31d0512cc
└─sda6   8:6    0  40,4G  0 part /
```

Previous files are on the sda1, and I did go through the LAMPP stack. Said apache2 was already installed, tho it did go through mysql installation.

Edit: All my terminal output

```
egils@linux:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for egils: 
Hit:1 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]    
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]     
Get:4 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]  
Hit:5 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                   
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease           
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release             
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages 
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages  
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages  
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages 
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages  
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages  
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages 
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages  
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages  
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages 
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages  
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages  
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages 
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages  
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages  
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Fetched 306 kB in 13s (23,4 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
egils@linux:~$ sudo apt-get install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
apache2 is already the newest version (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 122 not upgraded.
egils@linux:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libevent-core-2.0-5 libhtml-template-perl mysql-client-5.7
  mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
Suggested packages:
  libipc-sharedcache-perl mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libevent-core-2.0-5 libhtml-template-perl mysql-client-5.7
  mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.7
  mysql-server-core-5.7
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 122 not upgraded.
Need to get 18,6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 161 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-common all 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [15,6 kB]
Get:2 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libaio1 amd64 0.3.110-2 [6 356 B]
Get:3 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-client-core-5.7 amd64 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [6 339 kB]
Get:4 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-client-5.7 amd64 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [1 675 kB]
Get:5 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-server-core-5.7 amd64 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [7 670 kB]
Get:6 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libevent-core-2.0-5 amd64 2.0.21-stable-2ubuntu0.16.04.1 [70,6 kB]
Get:7 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-server-5.7 amd64 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [2 708 kB]
Get:8 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libhtml-template-perl all 2.95-2 [60,4 kB]
Get:9 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-server all 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [10,2 kB]
Fetched 18,6 MB in 36s (503 kB/s)                                              
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
(Reading database ... 212811 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common_5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libaio1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libaio1_0.3.110-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libaio1:amd64 (0.3.110-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-core-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-core-5.7_5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-5.7_5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-5.7_5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libevent-core-2.0-5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libevent-core-2.0-5_2.0.21-stable-2ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libevent-core-2.0-5:amd64 (2.0.21-stable-2ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.7.
(Reading database ... 212979 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhtml-template-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libhtml-template-perl_2.95-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhtml-template-perl (2.95-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu19) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Setting up libaio1:amd64 (0.3.110-2) ...
Setting up mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up libevent-core-2.0-5:amd64 (2.0.21-stable-2ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.95-2) ...
Setting up mysql-server (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu19) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
egils@linux:~$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
egils@linux:~$ sudo apache2clt configtest
sudo: apache2clt: command not found
egils@linux:~$ sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libapache2-mod-php7.0 libmcrypt4 php-common php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-common
  php7.0-json php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-mysql php7.0-opcache php7.0-readline
Suggested packages:
  php-pear libmcrypt-dev mcrypt
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libapache2-mod-php libapache2-mod-php7.0 libmcrypt4 php php-common
  php-mcrypt php-mysql php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-json
  php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-mysql php7.0-opcache php7.0-readline
0 upgraded, 15 newly installed, 0 to remove and 122 not upgraded.
Need to get 3 689 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14,8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 php-common all 1:35ubuntu6 [10,8 kB]
Get:2 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 php7.0-common amd64 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [843 kB]
Get:3 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 php7.0-json amd64 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [16,9 kB]
Get:4 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 php7.0-opcache amd64 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [77,1 kB]
Get:5 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 php7.0-readline amd64 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [12,8 kB]
Get:6 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 php7.0-cli amd64 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [1 287 kB]
Get:7 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libapache2-mod-php7.0 amd64 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [1 229 kB]
Get:8 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libapache2-mod-php all 1:7.0+35ubuntu6 [2 960 B]
Get:9 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 libmcrypt4 amd64 2.5.8-3.3 [63,0 kB]
Get:10 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 php7.0 all 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [1 294 B]
Get:11 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 php all 1:7.0+35ubuntu6 [2 832 B]
Get:12 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 php7.0-mcrypt amd64 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [14,5 kB]
Get:13 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 php-mcrypt all 1:7.0+35ubuntu6 [1 930 B]
Get:14 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 php7.0-mysql amd64 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [124 kB]
Get:15 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 php-mysql all 1:7.0+35ubuntu6 [1 936 B]
Fetched 3 689 kB in 6s (569 kB/s)                                              
Selecting previously unselected package php-common.
(Reading database ... 213080 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../php-common_1%3a35ubuntu6_all.deb ...
Unpacking php-common (1:35ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.0-common.
Preparing to unpack .../php7.0-common_7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0-common (7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.0-json.
Preparing to unpack .../php7.0-json_7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0-json (7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.0-opcache.
Preparing to unpack .../php7.0-opcache_7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0-opcache (7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.0-readline.
Preparing to unpack .../php7.0-readline_7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0-readline (7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.0-cli.
Preparing to unpack .../php7.0-cli_7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0-cli (7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libapache2-mod-php7.0.
Preparing to unpack .../libapache2-mod-php7.0_7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapache2-mod-php7.0 (7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libapache2-mod-php.
Preparing to unpack .../libapache2-mod-php_1%3a7.0+35ubuntu6_all.deb ...
Unpacking libapache2-mod-php (1:7.0+35ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmcrypt4.
Preparing to unpack .../libmcrypt4_2.5.8-3.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmcrypt4 (2.5.8-3.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.0.
Preparing to unpack .../php7.0_7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0 (7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php.
Preparing to unpack .../php_1%3a7.0+35ubuntu6_all.deb ...
Unpacking php (1:7.0+35ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.0-mcrypt.
Preparing to unpack .../php7.0-mcrypt_7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0-mcrypt (7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php-mcrypt.
Preparing to unpack .../php-mcrypt_1%3a7.0+35ubuntu6_all.deb ...
Unpacking php-mcrypt (1:7.0+35ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.0-mysql.
Preparing to unpack .../php7.0-mysql_7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0-mysql (7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php-mysql.
Preparing to unpack .../php-mysql_1%3a7.0+35ubuntu6_all.deb ...
Unpacking php-mysql (1:7.0+35ubuntu6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up php-common (1:35ubuntu6) ...
Setting up php7.0-common (7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/calendar.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/ctype.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/exif.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/fileinfo.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/ftp.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/gettext.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/iconv.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/pdo.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/phar.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/posix.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/shmop.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sockets.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sysvmsg.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sysvsem.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sysvshm.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/tokenizer.ini with new version
Setting up php7.0-json (7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/json.ini with new version
Setting up php7.0-opcache (7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/opcache.ini with new version
Setting up php7.0-readline (7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/readline.ini with new version
Setting up php7.0-cli (7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/php7.0 to provide /usr/bin/php (php) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/phar7.0 to provide /usr/bin/phar (phar) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/phar.phar7.0 to provide /usr/bin/phar.phar (phar.phar) in auto mode

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini with new version
Setting up libapache2-mod-php7.0 (7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini with new version
Module mpm_event disabled.
Enabling module mpm_prefork.
apache2_switch_mpm Switch to prefork
apache2_invoke: Enable module php7.0
Setting up libapache2-mod-php (1:7.0+35ubuntu6) ...
Setting up libmcrypt4 (2.5.8-3.3) ...
Setting up php7.0 (7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up php (1:7.0+35ubuntu6) ...
Setting up php7.0-mcrypt (7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mcrypt.ini with new version
Setting up php-mcrypt (1:7.0+35ubuntu6) ...
Setting up php7.0-mysql (7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mysqlnd.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mysqli.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/pdo_mysql.ini with new version
Setting up php-mysql (1:7.0+35ubuntu6) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for libapache2-mod-php7.0 (7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
egils@linux:~$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf
egils@linux:~$ sudo systemclt restart apache2
sudo: systemclt: command not found
egils@linux:~$ cat /atc/fstab
cat: /atc/fstab: No such file or directory
egils@linux:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=1ddb33aa-6ea5-478e-95df-6559477dfb70 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=2b3c62b4-ef69-4c19-aa30-c6a97e70d7a3 none            swap    sw              0       0
egils@linux:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   1  14,4G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1  14,4G  0 part /media/egils/UBUNTU 16_0
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
sda      8:0    0 111,8G  0 disk 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0     8G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda1   8:1    0  63,5G  0 part /media/egils/866e4a3f-54dd-4b90-807e-a31d0512cc
└─sda6   8:6    0  40,4G  0 part /
egils@linux:~$ sudo systemclt restart apache2
[sudo] password for egils: 
sudo: systemclt: command not found
egils@linux:~$ sudo install systemd
install: missing destination file operand after 'systemd'
Try 'install --help' for more information.
egils@linux:~$ init --help
init [OPTIONS...] {COMMAND}

Send control commands to the init daemon.

     --help      Show this help
     --no-wall   Don't send wall message before halt/power-off/reboot

Commands:
  0              Power-off the machine
  6              Reboot the machine
  2, 3, 4, 5     Start runlevelX.target unit
  1, s, S        Enter rescue mode
  q, Q           Reload init daemon configuration
  u, U           Reexecute init daemon
egils@linux:~$ service apache2 restart
egils@linux:~$ apt-cache search php5-
bluefish - advanced Gtk+ text editor for web and software development
egils@linux:~$ apt-cache search php7-

egils@linux:~$ 
egils@linux:~$ aptitude search php5-
egils@linux:~$ sudo apache2 status       
Usage: apache2 [-D name] [-d directory] [-f file]
               [-C "directive"] [-c "directive"]
               [-k start|restart|graceful|graceful-stop|stop]
               [-v] [-V] [-h] [-l] [-L] [-t] [-T] [-S] [-X]
Options:
  -D name            : define a name for use in <IfDefine name> directives
  -d directory       : specify an alternate initial ServerRoot
  -f file            : specify an alternate ServerConfigFile
  -C "directive"     : process directive before reading config files
  -c "directive"     : process directive after reading config files
  -e level           : show startup errors of level (see LogLevel)
  -E file            : log startup errors to file
  -v                 : show version number
  -V                 : show compile settings
  -h                 : list available command line options (this page)
  -l                 : list compiled in modules
  -L                 : list available configuration directives
  -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS  : show parsed vhost settings
  -t -D DUMP_RUN_CFG : show parsed run settings
  -S                 : a synonym for -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS -D DUMP_RUN_CFG
  -t -D DUMP_MODULES : show all loaded modules 
  -M                 : a synonym for -t -D DUMP_MODULES
  -t                 : run syntax check for config files
  -T                 : start without DocumentRoot(s) check
  -X                 : debug mode (only one worker, do not detach)
egils@linux:~$ service apache2 status
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since C  2017-11-09 11:26:15 EET; 10min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 15241 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCES
  Process: 15264 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCC
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─15281 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─15284 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─15285 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─15286 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─15287 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─15288 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

nov 09 11:26:14 linux systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
nov 09 11:26:14 linux apache2[15264]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache
nov 09 11:26:14 linux apache2[15264]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably deter
nov 09 11:26:15 linux apache2[15264]:  *
nov 09 11:26:15 linux systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
...skipping...
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since C  2017-11-09 11:26:15 EET; 10min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 15241 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCES
  Process: 15264 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCC
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─15281 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─15284 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─15285 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─15286 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─15287 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─15288 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

nov 09 11:26:14 linux systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
nov 09 11:26:14 linux apache2[15264]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache
nov 09 11:26:14 linux apache2[15264]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably deter
nov 09 11:26:15 linux apache2[15264]:  *
nov 09 11:26:15 linux systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
~
~
```

Comment: How did you reinstall Ubuntu ? I am assuming you used a USB stick?
When you do this, one of the early screens / options is about space : do you want to [A] install over everything, [B] install /next/ to existing OS [C] Do the partitioning yourself....
I may be wrong, but I suspect you may have chosen B.
If this is correct, my suggestion would be to back up everything [on a stand alone device] then reinstall using [A].

Comment: And I did use the UBS stick, and did chose B option. @Piloti

Comment: Hi...
I think [B] may be the root of the problem, because the new install is next to the other one and [I think] they do not allow each other access.....
If you don't need two installs, I would wash, rinse and repeat, using option [A]. After the back up.

Comment: Yea, I might try doing that. Also probably should not separate the drives. Thank you for your input! @piloti

Comment: Hang on, did you actually run `opt/lampp/lampp`? Or did you run `/opt/lampp/lampp`? The `/` is needed, without it, it will look for an `opt` directory in your current directory.

Comment: Yes, I did use the / before opt. It says sudo: /opt/lampp/lampp: command not found @terdon

Comment: OK, please [edit] your question then and make sure it accurately describes what you did. Also explain how you installed lampp, what the output was etc. Remember, we don't have access to any information unless you give it to us, and the more you explain, the likelier it is someone will be able to help you.

Comment: I added all my terminal output of today, to my original post. I am new to both Linux and this forums, so sorry for my mistakes. Also for that reason, there are some commands, that I ran in terminal, that probably shouldnt be there. as I'm still trying to learn. @terdon